# Why on calling plt.figure() in jupyter notebook, two figure appear?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

While plotting using matplotlib.pyplot on jupyter notebook, i have noticed that if i call the method

```
    plt.figure()
```

alone(nothing else in the cell) two identical empty figure appear. On the other hand, if i call

```
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot([1,3,4],[2,7,9])
```

then only on figure shows up on the screen.
Can anyone explain why this happens?

p.s. : I am using %matplotlib notebook magic function at the top, which i don't understand very well.

Comment: One more thing, if i don't use %matplotlib notebook, when i call plt.gca() a figure appears on the screen like a square.

Comment: Strange. In the first case, if you use `fig = plt.figure()`, then only one figure appears

Answer (score 1):

You have to think how jupyter notebooks work.
The last statement in a cell will be used as output.

`plt.figure() -> figure`
will produce one figure and post that figure separately as output, it will appear twice.

`plt.plot` or `fig = plt.figure()` produce no figure in the output